# NX3DV42 Routing

Tags: usb, multiplexer

Is it possible to use the NX3DV42 pins designated for USB Data + for Data - ? And use the pins designated for Data - for Data + ?

[image]

It is my understanding that because the NX3DV42 is essentially just a switch, either routing Method 1 or Method 2 would be acceptable.

Is this correct?

NX3DV42 Data Sheet:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NX3DV42.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. At the switch level, there is no difference between signal D+ and signal D-. Do your routing in most convenient way, but remember to maintain differential impedance on all D+/D- pairs at 90 Ohms.

Comment: Great, thank you. Would it be safe to assume the same concept with a USB 3 switch like the PI3USB302-A?    Data sheet: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PI3USB302-A.pdf

Comment: @M.P. For USB 3 it is even more: you can even swap + and - wires on Tx and Rx lanes; the electrical protocol has means to detect swapped polarity and achieve clock and symbol lock accordingly. This is built into 3.0 specifications.

Comment: One more quick question since you seem to know your USB stuff. Would adding a USB3.0 switch, like the PI3USB302-A result in having to add SSTX coupling capacitors on either side of it?  I'm making a small hobbyist board to learn more about this and don't want to make a simple mistake thats stops me before I start.

Comment: @M.P., are you familiar with such a category of  support documents from manufacturers as "reference design" boards? Please check this out: https://www.diodes.com/pericom-part-files/PI3USB302-A/Application%20information/30216A%20+%20302-A%20app%20sch%207%2022%2015.pdf It has the recommended application schematics, and correct (validated) placement of decoupling caps.